POLICE UK Data access API from POWER BI
I am trying to get access to Police data using API
https://data.police.uk/docs/method/crime-street/
and then
https://data.police.uk/api/crimes-street/all-crime?lat=52.629729&lng=-1.131592&date=2017-01
for example but it is not working when "Get data -> WEB -> then pasting https://data.police.uk/api/crimes-street/all-crime?lat=52.629729&lng=-1.131592&date=2017-01"
I am getting the error:

Details: "Web.Contents failed to get contents from 'https://data.police.uk/api/crimes-street/all-crime?lat=52.629729&lng=-1.131592&date=2017-01' (404): NOT FOUND"

This is what I found in the police API documentation:

The Police API no longer requires authentication.
Responses
If a request succeeds, the API will return a 200 status code.
If a request fails, the API will return a non-200 status code.


it works if you remove the date part, it is not liking the date for some reason

It looks like from the API, if the year month date part does not exist in the dataset, it returns a 404, not found message.
So for the above if you change the date to 2022-01
https://data.police.uk/api/crimes-street/all-crime?lat=52.629729&lng=-1.131592&date=2022-01
You do get an output of
[
{
    "category": "anti-social-behaviour",
    "location_type": "Force",
    "location": {
        "latitude": "52.631380",
        "street": {
            "id": 883322,
            "name": "On or near Upper Brown Street"
        },
        "longitude": "-1.135338"
    },
    "context": "",
    "outcome_status": null,
    "persistent_id": "",
    "id": 98506958,
    "location_subtype": "",
    "month": "2022-01"
},

Changing it back to 2017-01 returns 404, which is a non 200 status code.
